# MemoryStream read/write and data length

Tags: c#, .net, stream, memorystream, binarywriter

I have a MemoryStream /BinaryWriter , I use it as following:

```
memStram = new MemoryStream();
memStramWriter = new BinaryWriter(memStram);

memStramWriter(byteArrayData);
```

now to read I do the following:

```
byte[] data = new byte[this.BulkSize];
int readed = this.memStram.Read(data, 0, Math.Min(this.BulkSize,(int)memStram.Length));
```

My 2 question is:

1. After I read, the position move to currentPosition+readed , Does the
   memStram.Length will changed?
2. I want to init the stream (like I just create it), can I do the following instead using Dispose and new again, if not is there any faster way than dispose&new: ;

> ```
> memStram.Position = 0;
> memStram.SetLength(0);
> ```

Thanks.
Joseph

Comment: what is `memStramWriter(byteArrayData);` meant to be there? because that won't compile...

Comment: so... do you mean `memStramWriter.Write(byteArrayData)` ? And if so, why not just `memStram.Write(byteArrayData, 0, byteArrayData.Length)` ?

Answer (score 3):

1. No; why should Length (i.e. **data size**) change on *read*?
2. Yes; SetLength(0) is faster: there's *no overhead* with memory allocation and  re-allocation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> 1: After I read, the position move to currentPosition+readed , Does the memStram.Length will changed?

Reading doesn't usually change the `.Length` - just the `.Position`; but strictly speaking, it is a bad idea even to *look* at the `.Length` and `.Position` when reading (and often: when writing), as that is not supported on all streams. Usually, you read until (one of, depending on the scenario):

- until you have read an expected number of bytes, for example via some length-header that told you how much to expect
- until you see a sentinel value (common in text protocols; not so common in binary protocols)
- until the end of the stream (where `Read` returns a non-positive value)

I would also probably say: don't use `BinaryWriter`. There doesn't seem to be anything useful that it is adding over just using `Stream`.

> 2: I want to init the stream (like I just create it), can I do the following instead using Dispose and new again, if not is there any faster way than dispose&new:

Yes, `SetLength(0)` is fine *for `MemoryStream`*. It isn't necessarily fine in all cases (for example, it won't make much sense on a `NetworkStream`).

Answer (score 2):

No the lenght should not change, and you can easily inspect that with a watch variable

i would use the `using` statement, so the syntax will be more elegant and clear, and you will not forget to dispose it later...